# Pesquisar em texto GIGANTE

Tags: linux, otimização, texto

Eu tenho aqui comigo, um texto gigante, DESCOMUNAL, é um txt de aproximadamente 30 GIGABYTES, ele está comprimido em 7z
Eu quero pedir a ajuda de vocês, para saber como eu posso fazer pesquisas dentro dele, como um cat | grep, o que obviamente não funcionaria pelo tamanho do arquivo visto que eu tenho apenas 2GB de RAM, eu quero tentar fazer pesquisas no conteúdo dele, sem que minha máquina dê crash, de preferência sem precisar extrair

Comment: Adendo: o 7z tem 1.7 GB, 28 GB é descompactado

Comment: cat e grep funcionaria sim, esses comandos não retém o arquivo inteiro na memória, mas apenas o suficiente para fazer a pesquisa. Se você está procurando por uma palavra de 5 letras, em tese o grep manteria apenas 5 caracteres no buffer.

Comment: Já tentou usar `sed`?

Comment: @epx e como eu poderia utilizar cat | grep sem precisar extrair o arquivo, tem jeito?

Comment: @Danizavtz não tentei ainda, irei pesquisar

Comment: Utilize Sed ou AWK, pois não envia o arquivo todo para a memória para tentar ser processado.

Comment: Um "detalhe" que pode não necessariamente ser preciso aqui é lembrar da computação em nuvem. É possível usar saas, pass ou iass conforme as suas necessidades. Caso vc não tenha puder computacional ou memória suficiente para correr algo específico, pode-se levantar rapidamente uma máquina virtual, correr o processo e derrubar a VM em seguida.

Comment: Os parâmetros -so -bd pro 7z acho que resolvem

Comment: o ficheiro após descompactado é uma único ficheiro de texto?? Se não for indiscreto, donde veio esse ficheiro?

Comment: Foi daquela treta com o serasa, fiquei preocupado e decidi procurar coisas lá, ainda bem que não tinha coisa vazada